# Does a kernel driver's `release` file-operations handler wait for other fops to finish?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, race-condition

In the case of linux kernel device drivers there is the `file_operations` struct, or fops struct, which allows the driver to define handlers for various file operations.

My question is about the `.release` fop handler.

I know the `release` handler will *only* be called when the last file descriptor (fd) for the `file` object is closed (or munmapped). This is done when `fput` is called on the `file` and the `file->f_count` reaches 0.

However - I am unclear on if other file operations can be running simultaneously in a another thread when `release` is entered.

For example:

could 1 thread of a process be inside the `ioctl` handler for the `file` (or fd), while another thread of the same process is inside of the `release` handler?

Can `release` be a factor in race conditions for the `file` object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> could 1 thread of a process be inside the ioctl handler for the file (or fd), while another thread of the same process is inside of the release handler?

No. The *release* entry point is called when the reference counter on the
file entry is 0. *ioctl()* increments the reference counter on the file. So, the *release* entry point will not be called while an *ioctl()* is on tracks.

### Foreword

The source code discussed below is:

- GLIBC 2.31
- Linux 5.4

### GLIBC's pthread management

The GLIBC's *pthread_create()* actually involves a *clone()* system call with
the following flags:

```
CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID
```

According to the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) of *clone()*, the **CLONE_FILES** flag makes the threads of a process

> share the same file descriptor table. Any file descriptor created by

one thread is also valid in the other threads. Similarly, if one thread closes a file descriptor, or changes its associated flags (using the *fcntl()* **F_SETFD** operation), the other threads are also affected.

### clone() on the kernel side

When *clone()* is passed **CLONE_FILES**, the *files_struct* is not duplicated but a reference counter is incremented. As a consequence, the task structures of both threads point on the same *files_struct* (*files* field):

. The task structure is defined in *include/linux/sched.h*:

```c
struct task_struct {
[...]
    /* Open file information: */
    struct files_struct     *files; /// <==== Table of open files shared between thread
[...]
```

. In *kernel/fork.c*, the *clone()* service calls *copy_files()* to increment the reference counter on the *files_struct*

```c
static int copy_files(unsigned long clone_flags, struct task_struct *tsk)
{
    struct files_struct *oldf, *newf;
    int error = 0;

    /*
     * A background process may not have any files ...
     */
    oldf = current->files;
    if (!oldf)
        goto out;

    if (clone_flags & CLONE_FILES) {
      atomic_inc(&oldf->count);  // <==== Ref counter incremented: files_struct is shared
        goto out;
    }

    newf = dup_fd(oldf, &error);
    if (!newf)
        goto out;

    tsk->files = newf;
    error = 0;
out:
    return error;
}
```

. The *files_struct* is defined in *include/linux/fdtable.h*:

```c
/*
 * Open file table structure
 */
struct files_struct {
  /*
   * read mostly part
   */
        atomic_t count;  // <==== Reference counter
    bool resize_in_progress;
    wait_queue_head_t resize_wait;

    struct fdtable __rcu *fdt;
    struct fdtable fdtab;
  /*
   * written part on a separate cache line in SMP
   */
    spinlock_t file_lock ____cacheline_aligned_in_smp;
    unsigned int next_fd;
    unsigned long close_on_exec_init[1];
    unsigned long open_fds_init[1];
    unsigned long full_fds_bits_init[1];
    struct file __rcu * fd_array[NR_OPEN_DEFAULT];
```

### ioctl() operation

*ioctl()* system call is defined *fs/ioctl.c*. It calls *fdget()* first to increment the reference counter on the file entry, do the requested operation and then call *fdput()*

```c
int ksys_ioctl(unsigned int fd, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
    int error;
    struct fd f = fdget(fd);

    if (!f.file)
        return -EBADF;
    error = security_file_ioctl(f.file, cmd, arg);
    if (!error)
        error = do_vfs_ioctl(f.file, fd, cmd, arg);
    fdput(f);
    return error;
}

SYSCALL_DEFINE3(ioctl, unsigned int, fd, unsigned int, cmd, unsigned long, arg)
{
    return ksys_ioctl(fd, cmd, arg);
}
```

The *file* entry is defined in *include/linux/fs.h*. Its reference counter is the *f_count* field:

```c
struct file {
    union {
        struct llist_node   fu_llist;
        struct rcu_head     fu_rcuhead;
    } f_u;
    struct path     f_path;
    struct inode        *f_inode;   /* cached value */
    const struct file_operations    *f_op;

    /*
     * Protects f_ep_links, f_flags.
     * Must not be taken from IRQ context.
     */
    spinlock_t      f_lock;
    enum rw_hint        f_write_hint;
        atomic_long_t       f_count;  // <===== Reference counter
    unsigned int        f_flags;
[...]
} __randomize_layout
  __attribute__((aligned(4)));
```

### Example

Here is a simple device driver into which the file operations merely display a message when they are triggered. The *ioctl()* entry makes the caller sleep 5 seconds:

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/kdev_t.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>


MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

#define DEVICE_NAME "device"

static int device_open(struct inode *, struct file *);
static int device_release(struct inode *, struct file *);
static ssize_t device_read(struct file *, char *, size_t, loff_t *);
static ssize_t device_write(struct file *, const char *, size_t, loff_t *);
static long int device_ioctl(struct file *, unsigned int, unsigned long);
static int device_flush(struct file *, fl_owner_t);

static const struct file_operations fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .read = device_read,
    .write = device_write,
    .unlocked_ioctl = device_ioctl,
    .open = device_open,
    .flush = device_flush,
    .release = device_release
};

struct cdev *device_cdev;
dev_t deviceNumbers;

static  int __init init(void)
{
  // This returns the major number chosen dynamically in deviceNumbers
  int ret = alloc_chrdev_region(&deviceNumbers, 0, 1, DEVICE_NAME);

  if (ret < 0) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Error registering: %d\n", ret);
    return -1;
  }

  device_cdev = cdev_alloc();

  cdev_init(device_cdev, &fops);

  ret = cdev_add(device_cdev, deviceNumbers, 1);

  printk(KERN_INFO "Device initialized (major number is %d)\n", MAJOR(deviceNumbers));

  return 0;
}

static void __exit cleanup(void)
{
  unregister_chrdev_region(deviceNumbers, 1);

  cdev_del(device_cdev);

  printk(KERN_INFO "Device unloaded\n");
}

static int device_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "Device open\n");
  return 0;
}

static int device_flush(struct file *file, fl_owner_t id)
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "Device flush\n");
  return 0;
}

static int device_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "Device released\n");
  return 0;
}


static ssize_t device_write(struct file *filp, const char *buff, size_t len, loff_t * off)
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "Device write\n");
  return len;
}

static ssize_t device_read(struct file *filp, char *buff, size_t len, loff_t * off)
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "Device read\n");
  return 0;
}

static long int device_ioctl(struct file *file, unsigned int ioctl_num, unsigned long ioctl_param)
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "Device ioctl enter\n");
  msleep_interruptible(5000);
  printk(KERN_INFO "Device ioctl out\n");
  return 0;
}

module_init(init);
module_exit(cleanup);
```

Here is a user space program which involves the main thread and a secondary one. The main thread opens the above device and waits for the secondary thread to start (barrier) before closing the device after 1 second. Meanwhile, the secondary thread calls *ioctl()* on the above device which makes it sleep 5 seconds. Then it calls *ioctl()* a second time before exiting.
The expected behavior is to make the main thread close the device file while the secondary thread is running the *ioctl()*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

static int dev_fd;

static pthread_barrier_t barrier;


void *entry(void *arg)
{
  int rc;

  printf("Thread running...\n");

  // Rendez-vous with main thread
  pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);

  rc = ioctl(dev_fd, 0);
  printf("rc = %d, errno = %d\n", rc, errno);
  
  rc = ioctl(dev_fd, 0);
  printf("rc = %d, errno = %d\n", rc, errno);

  return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
  pthread_t tid;

  dev_fd = open("/dev/device", O_RDWR);

  pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, NULL, 2);

  pthread_create(&tid,NULL, entry, NULL);

  pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);

  sleep(1);

  close(dev_fd);

  pthread_join(tid,NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

Installation of the kernel module:

```
$ sudo insmod ./device.ko
$ dmesg
[13270.589766] Device initialized (major number is 237)
$ sudo mknod /dev/device c 237 0
$ sudo chmod 666 /dev/device 
$ ls -l /dev/device 
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 237, 0 janv.  27 10:55 /dev/device
```

The execution of the program shows that the first *ioctl()* makes the thread wait 5 seconds. But the second returns in error with **EBADF** (9) because meanwhile the device file has been closed by the main thread:

```
$ gcc p1.c -lpthread
$ ./a.out
Thread running...
rc = 0, errno = 0
rc = -1, errno = 9
```

In the kernel log, we can see that the *close()* in the main thread merely triggered a *flush()* operation on the device while the first *ioctl()* was on tracks in the secondary thread. Then, once the first *ioctl()* returned, the internals of the kernel freed the file entry (reference counter dropped to 0) and so, the second *ioctl()* did not reach the device as the file descriptor no longer referenced an opened file. Hence, the **EBADF** error on the second call:

```
[13270.589766] Device initialized (major number is 237)
[13656.862951] Device open        <==== Open() in the main thread
[13656.863315] Device ioctl enter <==== 1st ioctl() in secondary thread
[13657.863523] Device flush       <==== 1 s later, flush() = close() in the main thread
[13661.941238] Device ioctl out   <==== 5 s later, the 1st ioctl() returns
[13661.941244] Device released    <==== The file is released because the reference counter reached 0
```

Comment: One minor change in the 5.9 kernel is that the `ksys_ioctl` function's code has been merged into the `SYSCALL_DEFINE3(ioctl, unsigned int, fd, unsigned int, cmd, unsigned long, arg)` syscall handler itself, so that `ksys_ioctl` no longer exists as a separate function ([commit 863b67e15177a7cd0c27b3e36e42fe7907dec9bd](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=863b67e15177a7cd0c27b3e36e42fe7907dec9bd)). The behavior is the same though.

Comment: Ok. I will specify that my answer is based on Linux 5.4 sources. THANKS !

Comment: fantastic answer! thanks for the detailed overview. the example really drove this home for me. I think the clone bit may be a bit confusing as you mention the clone syscall incs the file count yet you still only close the fd once after created the thread.

But I understand  that the fd is shared across threads so closing the fd DOES close it for both threads. that's my only comment. Again - thanks so much. amazing answer. hope it helps others.